# How to get data from return

Tags: javascript, node.js

My function returns me data as shown below. How can I get specific information from this data, for example `country`?

```
[ { latitude: 52.6997543,
    longitude: 15.2602551,
    country: 'Poland',
    city: 'Gorzów Wielkopolski',
    state: 'Lubusz Voivodeship',
    zipcode: '66-446',
    streetName: 'Zieleniecka',
    streetNumber: '4',
    countryCode: 'pl',
    county: 'Gorzów Wielkopolski',
    extra: { confidence: 10, confidenceKM: 0.25 },
    provider: 'opencage' } ]
```

this is my function:

```
fn: async function({address, country, zipCode}){
        // const location = address + ' ' + city
        const response = await geocoder.geocode({
            address: address,
            country: country,
            zipcode: zipCode,
            minConfidence: 0.5,
            limit: 1
        })
        return response
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave you an upvote. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is an object contained within a list, you can access the country property like below:

```js
var list = [ { latitude: 52.6997543,
    longitude: 15.2602551,
    country: 'Poland',
    city: 'Gorzów Wielkopolski',
    state: 'Lubusz Voivodeship',
    zipcode: '66-446',
    streetName: 'Zieleniecka',
    streetNumber: '4',
    countryCode: 'pl',
    county: 'Gorzów Wielkopolski',
    extra: { confidence: 10, confidenceKM: 0.25 },
    provider: 'opencage' } ];
    
console.log(list[0].country);
```